# capture the value of an element in array returned by simpleXML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, http-post

Any idea how can i get a single value from an element in array returned by an XML which looks like this?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [id] => 0
        [description] => Success
    )
    ......
```

I want to capture the [id] and return that value to run tests against it.

the above was captured using the following

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this  `$id = $xml->status->id;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement("<statuses><status><id>0</id><description>success</description></status></statuses>");
var_dump((string) $sxml->status[0]->id);
```